# How to pass one response other request in Angular 7 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Hi i am working on my Angular 7 project. I am getting one response from a api and i want to integrate that response to other api which result success in all other apis.

Here is my code :

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.second()
}

first() {
  this.service.getId(id).resp.subscribe((res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.firstresp = res;
  });
}

second() {
  this.service.getId(this.firstresp).resp.subscribe((res => {
    console.log(res)
  });
}
```

Here the problem is first function executed properly and second function i am getting response only after refreshing the page. Any solution? TIA.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an RXJS question, not an angular one. You want to use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap):

```
this.service.getId(id).resp.pipe(
   switchMap((res) => {
      return this.service.getId(res).resp;
   })
).subscribe((rep) => {
 ....
});
```

switchMap above pipes the result of the first call into the second one then emits that result to the subscribe. No need for the `firstresp` etc.

Comment: In this subscribe if i am console it i am getting error message. First in switchmap the response i am getting is fine.